# How do I test routes made with the app router in NextJS? I'm using vitest for this

Tags: javascript, testing, next.js, vitest, app-router

I´m trying to test routes with vitest on next js 14.1.0. Is this possible? i don´t find any information about that.

i´m expecting some ideas to implement these tests on my project just like i did with jest and react router in other projects.

Comment: What do you mean "test routes"? i.e. what logic do you wish to make assertions about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about routes as in [route handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) you can use the [node-mocks-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mocks-http) package to test your routes, this package will simulate a request made to an endpoint. Here is an example:

```js
// @vitest-environment node

import { expect, test } from "vitest";
import { createRequest } from "node-mocks-http";

import { GET } from "app/api/users/route";

test("User endpoint works as expected", async () => {
  const source = "/tests/login.test.ts";

  const nextUrl = new URL(source, process.env.HOST);
  const request = createRequest({ method: "GET", url: "/api/users" });
  const response = await GET({ ...request, nextUrl } as any);

  expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  // ...
});
```

As you can see in the above test we create a mock http request and directly pass it to the route handler function without an actual HTTP request.